# Can the order in which a DNS entry is looked up be changed?

Tags: linux, dns

Can the order in which an entry is looked up at the DNS or the hosts (/etc/hosts) be specified on Linux?

E.g.: If I specify DNS then hosts then the name should be resolved using DNS first, and hosts on fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this is done with the /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/nsswitch.conf files.  For determining the order, look at the "**hosts**" line of *nsswitch.conf*.

*nsswitch.conf* is where you configure the name service switching.  This is a pretty standard one from a Debian Lenny system:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

# ...    

# HERE          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

*resolv.conf* lists your DNS servers and which domain names should be appended to the hostname by default.  It's likely generated automagically by your DHCP client.

```
search lan
nameserver x.x.x.x
```

Comment: A quick but very detailed and good answer, +1.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i remember putting the resolver order in *resolv.conf* once upon a time.  the "order" keyword, i think, which is still used in *host.conf*.  eg `order hosts, bind, nis` or `order bind, hosts, nis`.  it's the same syntax tho "man resolv.conf" doesn't make any mention of the keyword.

Comment: I was able to change the order in "hosts:" in nsswitch.conf 
Thanks a lot for your help.
Your answer was very quick and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Look for /etc/host.conf.  `man host.conf` for more info.